# SAP HANA calculated column - get last month data

Tags: calculated-columns, hana

I had created a calculated column to get last month data by subtracting '1' from month using the following code:

`string(int(rightstr(leftstr(string(now()),7),2))-1)`

But it doesn't work when it's january (january = 1, so 1-1 = 0).

I have already researched about if else statement, but didn't find about it in Column Engine language.

Tried the following code, but doesn't work.

`if('ActualMonth'='1', string(int("MesAtual")+11), 
    if("ActualMonth" > '1', 'ActualMonth', string(int('ActualMonth')-1))
)`

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As provided in https://answers.sap.com/questions/12942257/sap-hana-calculated-column-get-last-month-data.html one way to do this efficiently is using **date functions** :

```
component( addmonths(now(), -1) , 2)
```

This form

1. takes the current **server** time (*now()*) ,
2. substracts one month (by adding -1)
3. and extracts the date *component* 2 (month).

More on this can be found in the [reference documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/57a523b496cc4531a3676f5d94644899/2.0.04/en-US/d5546c7e7da24b2db555c8ef2cdc91f0.html).